# Value in a cell range greater than a value in another range with countif in excel

Tags: excel

I need to make a countif that works off of a few different elements, the code I have so far I have put below which counts the rows where values in column E and F are both above 0 for a specific name:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,Q63,E:E,">0",F:F,">0")
```

Now I want to add an element into this where it will only count if the value in column E is greater then F, this is what I tried but it did not work:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,Q63,E:E,">0",F:F,">0",E:E,">"&F:F)
```

Comment: What is in **Q63** ??

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B:B=Q63)*(E:E>0)*(F:F>0)*(E:E>F:F))
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW: Because you are multiplying all the Boolean expressions together the `--` is not really needed, it does not hurt either.  It is only needed if there is only one Boolean expression.